# How to set the Clutser Deformer weights using Maya Python API 2.0?

Tags: python, maya, maya-api

This is the incomplete code, my inputs are mention in this codes (cluster, geometry and its values). Which class i can use for set the cluster weights?. Is it possible to use maya.api.OpenMayaAnim.MFnSkincluster to set cluster weights.

```
import maya.api.OpenMaya as om
import maya.api.OpenMayaAnim as oma

#inputs    
myCluster   = ['cluster1', 'clusterHandle']
meshShape   = 'pSphereShape'

vertexList  = [1,2,3,4,5]
weights     = [1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]

#To MObject    
clusterList     = om.MSelectionList () 
clusterList.add (myCluster[0])
clusterMObject  = clusterList.getDependNode (0)

meshList        = om.MSelectionList () 
meshList.add (myCluster[0])
meshMObject     = meshList.getDependNode (0)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you found a solution for this problem yet?

Comment: No, R and D is going on.

Answer (score 0):

There are two useful posts showing how to use `OpenMaya.MPlug()` class instead of `OpenMayaAnim.MFnSkinCluster.setWeights()` and `MFnSkinCluster.setBlendWeights()`.

[Dealing with skinCluster weights in Maya](http://www.charactersetup.com/tutorial_skinWeights.html)

[Setting blendShape weights through Maya API](https://soup-dev.websitetoolbox.com/post/setting-blendshape-weights-through-maya-api-7116714)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge with me, But Actually I want to manage only the Cluster weights, I  want to set cluster weights in geometry, not a skin cluster.